# [Azure Web Sever + Unity]: Authentication Issues

Tags: azure, authentication, unity-game-engine, azure-web-app-service, html

I was trying to access and open a .jpg file with Unity Engine. In order to do that, I create a Web Service (following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet). Everything went fine and I am able to upload any kind of files and open it.

However, every time I want to go inside the URL from my webpage and try to access a specific file, I have to give my credentials to access the ﻿https://<>.azurewebsites.net webpage.

In my case, this is an important drawback since I need to have the possibility of accessing the webpage without any kind of identification; otherwise, an error would jump in Unity (specifically the 401: Unauthorized Access).

I tried to change the "Managed Service Identity" and the "Authentication/Authorization" field off. However, this didn't fix the problem nor made any changes.

I wanted to know if you could help me with this issue. I've been stuck with this problem all morning and don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try to visit the url of jpg to check if it works well. If it works, you could try to create a new webapp on azure and add the jpg file through kudu. Visit the url in azure web app and check if it will get 401 error.

Comment: I've created a new Web Sever. Know I can access freely to the main menu (for my case: http://myfirstazurewebserver.azurewebsites.net/). But I can't access to the sources I uploaded without authorization (with authorization I don't have any problem), even if I tried with kudu (I put the folder on the wwwroot, called 'Data'). Any clue about what could be going on? Thanks!